# Can I select multiple 'first-of-type's in a set of siblings via jQuery?

Tags: jquery

In this example, is there a way to use jQuery/js to select the first of each group of '.two' divs among siblings (i.e., a, d and i)?

```
<div>
    <div class='two'>a</div>
    <div class='one'>b</div>
    <div class='one'>c</div>
    <div class='two'>d</div>
    <div class='two'>e</div>
    <div class='two'>f</div>
    <div class='one'>g</div>
    <div class='one'>h</div>
    <div class='two'>i</div>
    <div class='two'>j</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/)

```js
$('.two:first-child, :not(.two) + .two').each(function() {
  console.log(this.textContent);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div class='two'>a</div>
  <div class='one'>b</div>
  <div class='one'>c</div>
  <div class='two'>d</div>
  <div class='two'>e</div>
  <div class='two'>f</div>
  <div class='one'>g</div>
  <div class='one'>h</div>
  <div class='two'>i</div>
  <div class='two'>j</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is probably the way I'll go since the divs in between might be different classes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One option is to combine the selectors `.two:first-child` and `.one + .two`:

```js
$('.two:first-child, .one + .two').each(function() {
  console.log(this.textContent);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div class='two'>a</div>
    <div class='one'>b</div>
    <div class='one'>c</div>
    <div class='two'>d</div>
    <div class='two'>e</div>
    <div class='two'>f</div>
    <div class='one'>g</div>
    <div class='one'>h</div>
    <div class='two'>i</div>
    <div class='two'>j</div>
</div>
```

(also note that you probably want to change the `<div>`s at the end of each line to `</div>` - you want to *end* the divs, not start a new div, at the end of a line)

Comment: To be more general you could use `:not(.two) + .two`

Comment: Whooops, rookie mistake with the </div>—this is not an issue in my actual code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The :first-of-type selector matches elements that have no other element with both the same parent and the same element name coming before it in the document tree.
Find the first span in each matched div and add a class to it.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>first-of-type demo</title>
  <style>
  span.fot {
    color: red;
    font-size: 120%;
    font-style: italic;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div>
  <span>Text1,</span>
  <span>Text2,</span>
  <span>Text3,</span>
  <span>Text4</span>
</div>
<div>
  <b>Demo1,</b>
  <span>Demo2,</span>
  <span>Demo3,</span>
  <span>Demo4</span>
</div>
 
<script>
$( "span:first-of-type" ).addClass( "fot" );
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```